# Use Array's Type in Extension Method

Tags: arrays, swift, set, swift2

What I'm trying to do is create an extension for an Array to check if all the elements are unique. My plan was to create a Set and check the Set's count to the Array's count. However, I'm not sure how to bind the Set's type to the same Type as the Array.

```
extension Array {
    func unique() -> Bool {
        var set = Set<self>()
        // Now add all the elements to the set
        return set.count == self.count
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Array` type is defined as

```
public struct Array<Element>
```

so `Element` is the generic placeholder and you can create
a `Set` with the same element type as

```
let set = Set<Element>()
```

But you have to require that the array elements are `Hashable`:

```
extension Array where Element : Hashable { ... }
```

(The possibility to define extension methods for generic types 
with restrictions on the type placeholder was added in Swift 2.)

Finally, with `set = Set(self)` the set's type is inferred automatically:

```
extension Array where Element : Hashable {
    func unique() -> Bool {
        let set = Set(self)
        return set.count == self.count
    }
}
```

Comment: whats `hashable` mean?

Comment: @Dustin: `Hashable` is a *protocol*, see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Hashable_Protocol/index.html.

Comment: Awesome, I knew it had to be something simple. Thanks!